# 1 to 1 spatial join

Tags: arcgis-desktop, shapefile, vector, spatial-join

I have a point data set containing crop type and a polygon data set regarding land parcels. I want to assess the point data integrity and ensure there is only one point, and no more in each polygon.

How do I do this?

I am using ArcGIS.

Comment: Please [Edit] the question to specify the data source(s) involved and choose one GIS software package (multiple packages make this multiple questions, which is forbidden).

Comment: Please specify the data format. An enterprise geodatabase would have different options.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using QGIS, you may run the **Join attributes by location** algorithm from the Processing Toolbox and set these parameters:

[image]

The algorithm will return a new point layer that stores some statistics and a new field (named `"COUNT"`) containing the number of polygon features intersected by each point feature: in this way, you should easily accomplish your task.

Comment: @sineadbrack I'm glad it worked! if this solution worked for you and you think to use it, please edit your question by adding the QGIS tag.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using ArcGIS, the steps are by right clicking on the polygon shapefile on your ToC and choose Join and Relates, and select Join..., Select the option "Join data from another layer based on spatial location", as seen below.

[image: Spatial Join in ArcGIS]

Comment: hi @Khaliff thank you so much for your reply. Is there any way of knowing if there is only one point on each polygon?

Comment: Once the spatial join is done, you can check the attribute table. There should be a new field/column "count" where you can examine how many points are there within each polygon. The 'average', 'sum', 'SD', etc options provides respective new fields as well.